# Create a new class in an existing ontology using SPARQL

Tags: class, sparql, semaphore

I am new and in a learning phase of ontologies and SPARQL query. I have an existing ontology in Semaphore and I would like to select specific triples using regex and put them under a new class.

The ids are arranged in an ontology like shown below (in Semaphore).

```
-->DummyOnto
QR1
NC1
QR2
QR3
NC2
UZ1
UZ2
UZ3
```

I have following SPARQL query, to select the triples which starts with QR and NC, which is working fine.

```
SELECT * WHERE 
  {
  {?s ?p ?o .
  filter regex(str(?s), "http://aaaaaa/sssss/eeeeee#QR-").
  }
  union
  {?s ?p ?o .
    filter regex(str(?s), "http://aaaaaa/sssss/eeeeee#NC").
  }
 } 
LIMIT 100
```

I would like put them in separate classes as shown below.

```
-->DummyOnto
---->ClassA
     QR1
     NC1
     QR2
     QR3
     NC2
---->ClassB
     UZ1
     UZ2
     UZ3
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The [tag:semaphore] tag is not for the product (I can’t suggest an edit to remove it, because the queue is full).

Answer (score 0):

This SPARQL UPDATE query inserts the triple specified inside `INSERT` for all `?s` that were found inside `WHERE`:

```
INSERT {

  ?s a :ClassA .

}

WHERE {

  ?s ?p ?o .

  FILTER ( 
    STRSTARTS(STR(?s), "http://aaaaaa/sssss/eeeeee#QR") 
    || 
    STRSTARTS(STR(?s), "http://aaaaaa/sssss/eeeeee#NC") 
  ) .

}
```

If there is a property that *all* `?s` have, it would improve performance to specify this property instead of `?p`.

Further changes:

- instead of `REGEX`: [`STRSTARTS`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strstarts)
- instead of `UNION`: [`||`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-logical-or) ("OR") inside the `FILTER`

---

If performance is an issue, you could test this variant, which uses a subquery so that `SELECT` can be specified:

```
INSERT {
  ?s a :ClassA .
}

WHERE {

  {
    SELECT ?s
    WHERE {
      ?s ?p ?o .
      FILTER ( STRSTARTS(STR(?s), "http://aaaaaa/sssss/eeeeee#QR") || STRSTARTS(STR(?s), "http://aaaaaa/sssss/eeeeee#NC") ) .
    }
  }

}
```