# Conditional insertion of a new concept class to an ontology model

Tags: sparql, ontology

I am in a learning phase of SPARQL and ontology building. I have a model and I would like to add a new concept class to multiple concepts in a model using regex/filter.

I have following concepts:

```
A647674
A878678
RR36868   
DD36868
```

The expected output is :

```
A647674   
A878678   
RR36868 rdf:type  http://schemas.aaaaaaa.com/ontologies/drug#SmallMolecule
DD36868 rdf:type  http://schemas.aaaaaaa.com/ontologies/drug#SmallMolecule
```

I am using below SPARQL query to do this.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

INSERT { 
    ?s rdf:type 'http://schemas.aaaaaaa.com/ontologies/drug#SmallMolecule' . 
}
WHERE 
  {
  {?s ?p ?o .
  filter regex(str(?s), "http://ontology.aaaaaaa.com/drugs/aaaaaaa#RR-").
  }
  union
  {?s ?p ?o .
    filter regex(str(?s), "http://ontology.aaaaaaa.com/drugs/aaaaaaa#DD").
  }
 };
#LIMIT 100
```

I am getting below error using above query.

```
OmServerGenericException[message="http://schemas.aaaaaaa.com/ontologies/drug#SmallMolecule",responseCode=500]
Caused by: org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ResourceRequiredException: "http://schemas.aaaaaaa.com/ontologies/drug#SmallMolecule"
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: URIs are wrapped in angle brackets or prefixed, you should write `INSERT { 
    ?s rdf:type <http://schemas.aaaaaaa.com/ontologies/drug#SmallMolecule> . 
}`

Comment: you can also simplify your query as a `FILTER` allows for the disjunction of expressions via `||`  so do  `filter(REGEX1 || REGEX2)` or even smarter, put the alternative into a single regex

Answer (score 0):

You are providing a string value:

```
?s rdf:type 'http://schemas.aaaaaaa.com/ontologies/drug#SmallMolecule' .
```

You need to provide a URI value:

```
?s rdf:type <http://schemas.aaaaaaa.com/ontologies/drug#SmallMolecule> .
```

Or you could define a prefix (`PREFIX drug: <http://schemas.aaaaaaa.com/ontologies/drug#>`) to use it like this:

```
?s rdf:type drug:SmallMolecule .
```

(The suggestions given in my [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73860212/19579546) apply here, too: you could use `STRSTARTS` instead of `REGEX`, and one `FILTER` with `||` instead of `UNION`.)